# How to Create Arrow navigation for Content slider or Content carousel or Content Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

[image]

i am looking for the above model i don't know what we call this, searched in Google in different name combination etc but i have not got the right one.

what i need is on click of arrow it should move to the next set of content from the current one smoothly just like an image slider and also if clicked the previous arrow it should load previous content

Comment: 1.You have to calculate the page count. 2. Arrange the pages in sequence. 3. Set the `overflow` of parent to `hidden`. 4. Change the `margin` or `left` css using `animate` function in `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these plugin as it will be helpful for horizontal slider also vertical one with custom arrow and inbuild arrow too

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Answer (score 1):

Long answer short, try Owl Carousel, a jQuery plugin that should easily solve your problem:
http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

You'll of course require our own CSS to style the carousel as you need.